# Corona SDK, spikes in delta time, and a few other questions

Tags: lua, coronasdk, game-engine, timedelta

1. I'm calculating delta time for use in my animations.  I notice randomly i get a spike in dt causing my player to fall through the floor.  it happens after a minute or two if i dont touch the screen. I'm sure this is the cause because I'm printing it when it's greater than 0.1.  this is my method of calculating dt

   ```
   local dt = 0
   local lastUpdate = 0

   function getDeltaTime()
       if lastUpdate == 0 then
           dt = 0
       else
           dt = (system.getTimer( ) - lastUpdate) / 1000
       end
       lastUpdate = system.getTimer( )
   end
   ```

   any idea why there are huge spikes in dt?
2. I'm using Dusk which is a great library.   I add it to my project like so.
   `local dusk = require "Dusk.Dusk"`

right now the dusk folder is sitting in the root of my project.  i wanted to sitck it in a lib folder.  i try including it this way

`local dusk = require "lib/Dusk.Dusk"`

or this way
`local dusk = require "lib.Dusk.Dusk"`

with the first way it says these files must be included using a "."  and in the second method it says
module 'Dusk.dusk_core.core' not found:

i'd figure this would be pretty straightforward,not sure what im doing wrong.

3. my third question is about accessing variables from the scene in an outside class.  for example, lets say i create a "Player" file with all the functionality related to my player.  I add the player in game.lua, and I want to call a function from my "game.lua" file within "player.lua"  whats the best way to reach those functions or varaiables?

Answer (score 1):

1. Try using `os.time` instead of `system.getTimer`. In some cases after suspending and resuming app, `system.getTimer` may start to count from beginning. Instead of `os.time` which is normal epoch timer.

   ```
   function getDeltaTime()
       if lastUpdate == 0 then
           dt = 0
       else
           dt = os.time() - lastUpdate
       end
       lastUpdate = os.time()
   end
   ```
2. When using require always use dots and always refer to it form where `main.lua` is.

`local dusk = require "lib.Dusk.Dusk"` seems to be ok if `lib` folder is exactly in same folder where you have `main.lua` file.

3. You may access it by events. So for example:

player.lua file:

```
local fireBullet function(event)
    if event and event.grenade then
        print("grenadeeee!!!")
    else
        print("fireeeee!!")
    end
end

Runtime:addEventListener("eventFireGun", fireBullet)
```

other file:

```
Runtime:dispatchEvent({ name = "eventFireGun", grenade = true })
```

It will call fireBullet no mater where it is. You don't have to keep it's reference.

You only have to remember to remove event listener BEFORE removing player object:

```
Runtime:removeEventListener("eventFireGun", fireBullet)
```

Otherwise player object won't be removed and it will cause huge memory leak.

Comment: thanks for the answer. some good info here.  os.time() returns time in seconds instead of milliseconds which doesnt really work well... any alternatives?

Comment: It's only because I suppose that system.getTimer may be reseted to 0 after suspending the app. You said it happens after minute or two, so phone may be already locked by the lock timer. It might happen to app also.